# Disambiguation of the [python] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

This is a major pet peeve of mine. Somebody posts a question for Python 3.x, but doesn't state that they're running 3.x. There's very few context clues at all, in fact. I, with my knowledge of Python 2.7, try to answer the question from that standpoint. My answer attracts more questions, though, when I'm using `print` statements with no parentheses, `raw_input` instead of `input`, and that weird, funky `reduce` thing.

Here's the root issue at hand: Because Python 2.x and Python 3.x are nearly incompatible, should the `python` tag be removed/retired/disambiguated so that all new questions describe which version of Python they use?

Comment: No keep the `python` tag. If you're uncertain which version the OP is using, you can always ask for clarification in the comments, or sometimes it's possible to find hints within the OP's code. I usually try to answer with both versions in mind (writing a version compatible solution), or I would provide two solutions if absolutely necessary.

Comment: What benefit does keeping the tag provide, as opposed to the two [python-2.x] and [python-3.x] tags? While I admit that an inexperienced user of python might not know which version they're using (and thus won't be able to post,) the majority of python users understand which version they're on.

Comment: @JakobLovern: "*What benefit does keeping the tag provide*" Well, it provides the benefit of not having to retag the no doubt *thousands* of questions that already use it.

Comment: @NicolBolas 811,539, at the moment. You have a valid point.

Comment: I think the best idea would be to use `python` in combination with `python-2.x` or `python-3.x` in the case of the questions where the version is relevant. But the question is useful, and the answer is "no".

Comment: I normally see the `python` tag used together with `python-2.x` and `python-3.x`. No need to remove it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There already exists ways to help disambiguate these questions:

- the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag which can be added to questions
- commenting to the OP and asking them to specify their version (and flagging as "unclear" if it's unclear if they're using one version or the other, and an answer hinges on a specific version)

Removing the overall [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag would be a poor solution to what really isn't a problem.  The only thing we can ask is that the OP provide relevant information (which would readily include interpreter version); not doing so can result in their question being closed.