# Google Sheets topicality and burnination of [google-sheets]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

There are a lot of questions about Google Sheets (essentially a hosted version Excel on the cloud, with less functionality).

We even have a tag for it.

- [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)

Many of these questions seem like it's way out of the purview of the site, and more fit for something like WebApps.StackExchange.com, or SuperUser. The tag wiki says,

> Questions related to Google Sheets and interacting with Google Sheets programmatically.

Not to be a snob, but is it "programmatically interacting" when you've got a proprietary end-user spreadsheet "formula"? We already have custom more-specific tags,

- for the API: [google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api)
- for the macro language: [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)
- for the `QUERY` language: [google-query-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-query-language)

What's left? Questions that amount to "how do I use my Excel on the Google Cloud?"

- [Google sheets - Sum of values in excel with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041069/google-sheets-sum-of-values-in-excel-with-condition)
- [Conditional formatting based on another cell's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-value)
- [Google Spreadsheet: Count rows with not empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081707/google-spreadsheet-count-rows-with-not-empty-value)
- [Apply formula to the entire column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941209/apply-formula-to-the-entire-column)

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? I see no issues...

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms you might find the answer on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365106/1595451

Comment: I think he was trying to say, "why in the hell is Excel on this site?!?!!! Evan has a **really** good argument here. Why would anyone disagree with him?" But, I'm not sure. I could have read that wrong.

Answer (score 16):

The Google Sheets tag certainly is on-topic.

You have an API which is on-topic, macros written in apps script which is on-topic, a function to query the sheet itself using an SQL-like language which is on-topic, and worksheet formulas which are dubious (the Excel excerpt says *complex worksheet formula development* is on-topic, I don't see why Google Sheets should be different).

Most of these concepts have their own tags, but that doesn't mean there shouldn't be a common tag that can be used by people with knowledge of all these subjects to browse questions they might be able to answer.

Unfortunately, similar to the Excel tag, the Google Sheets tag is bound to attract off-topic questions, and these should be closed as such. But that's no reason to burn down the entire tag.

Comment: *"Google Sheets lets you record macros that duplicate a specific series of UI interactions that you define."* I'm not sure that's on topic either. If you're writing the macro, you're using [tag:google-apps-script], right? Likewise the **pseudo**-sql thing is covered by [tag:google-query-language]

Comment: As said, these concepts have their own tags, macros indeed are Google Apps Script, and the query language also has it's own tag. That doesn't mean that this tag is inappropriate because there are more specific tags. If that was a rule, we could also go about burninating Android, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a fair comparison. Android users could not know what better tag to use, or perhaps there is no better tag to use. [Like in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id), what tags are missing for a unique device id on Android? The same doesn't seem true for this. You have more specific tags that cover all the bases. Generally, when a tag becomes vague we **do** stop using it, like `google` itself.

Comment: Well, we've gone a weird way by making [tag:android-api] a synonym of [tag:android], so users can't specify they're interested in a specific feature of the Android API. But the general point remains: we don't burninate tags just because there are more specific tags that cover the entire subject. That's also why we [declined the burnination of Python](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360372/7296893), for example.

Comment: But that's precisely the opposite of what happened with Android API. The Android API is upgraded with each version of Android. So you're supposed to tag it with the *specific* version instead. You can't use the API without using a version of Android. So why does Android exist? Well because some questions are applicable to all areas of Android, unlike anything that we're talking about here.

Comment: Well, the question you've provided should've been specific to one version of the Android API, now it's got multiple _valid for this version of the API_ answers. Can you provide a question that's narrow, on-topic and about Android in general? Questions like _how do I achieve this general goal_ could be asked for Google Spreadsheets as well, and an answer could either be a macro or a query, but are a bit broad imo, just like that Android question. Plus the point remains: _we don't burninate for that reason_

Comment: Sure, "Does flashing Android on my phone create problems with the Sprint PRL?"

Comment: Off-topic -> general computing, flashing an Android phone is not programming related

Comment: I think for any question *goals* on a spreasheet you *could* answer it with a macro, or a sufficiently advanced query. But, I don't think StackOverflow is the right place to ask spreadsheet questions. (which is the point)

Comment: (lame) "When rolling an install for a custom AOSP for Sprint how do I install and update the PRL?"

Comment: Should be tagged [tag:android-source] since that's more specific

Comment: I'm not sure you're point here. if it's that android already has a slew of non-specific vague tags too. Then sure! You've proven that. You can certainly have an insane amount of vague tags, and if you create enough vague tags, you can convince anyone that there is a problem. I would argue `google-sheets` is a vague tag. Is Android a vague tag? If everything in Android breaks down into other non-overlapping tags, then yes!

Comment: My point is: this is an invalid reason to delete a tag. We have more general tags (like android and google-sheets) that describe a general subject, and we have more specific tags that describe a subject within that general subject. We shouldn't delete any, we should just use the appropriate tags for a question: both the general and the specific one. And it's unfortunate the general ones tend to attract off-topic questions only tagged with that one, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree. You listed 3 separate on-topic Google Sheets related topics, in fact. There are plenty of programming-related questions about Google Sheets.

The fact that there are more specific tags for these does not prove that we should burninate this tag. By that logic, we should burninate the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag because there are already vendor-specific tags.

Comment: I do think they should burninate the SQL tag. And, in other places where people better understand SQL, and the tag, they did precisely that. https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3038/2639.

Comment: @EvanCarroll There was [a request to burninate that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360728/burninate-sql), but it was already declined.