# Is this question regarding Google Sheets off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, specific-question

I recently have been seeing a lot of questions regarding Google Sheets on Stack Overflow, such as this one:

[Calculate Number of Months and Days until Birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73664941/calculate-number-of-months-and-days-until-birthday)

It seems that it there is some basic level scripting and commands involved sometimes, and at the same time I have a hard time classifying it as software development.

I am not sure if it would be appropriate to flag such questions as being "blatantly off-topic". If yes, why, and if no, why not?

Comment: IMO writing formulae =/= "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". It's nothing to do with Google Sheets per say– if there's scripting involved, I think that's covered under that clause. But I don't think just using/ generating formulas in a spreadsheet fits with that. Not to mention the tag guidance in [the \[google-sheets\] excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets/info): "*Use this tag for questions about interacting with Google Sheets programmatically.*"

Comment: Also some related discussion here: [Google Sheets topicality and burnination of \[google-sheets\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376428)

Comment: @zcoop98 While you are welcome to write up your own answer to [the original version of this duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261875/11810933), the community consensus in that question was that formulas are on-topic.  It seems to me that they typically involve multiple (often nested) function calls, conditionals, data structures, and other elements common to a *programming language*.  Looking at the linked question from this particular meta question, I don't think we would ever expect that a "non-programmer" could propose those answers.

Comment: IMHO there are other [tag:google-sheets] questions that are a lot better (on-topic, good quality). Do not close a question just because it's about Google Sheets / spreadsheet formulas or because you found it to be "basic" / "beginner level". (please see my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420294/is-this-question-regarding-google-sheets-off-topic-on-stack-overflow#comment926096_420295)  to one of the answers here).

Comment: Re *"I recently have been seeing a lot"*: Whoa! That example is a work order. Requirements plus some input data. Is this tag becoming a new [homework tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions as a whole can be on-topic provided they adhere to the other on-topic rules; if the question's about a programming aspect of Google Sheets, it's fine. If it's just about using them, it's off-topic. Questions about formulas are dubious at best; if there are complex formulas being chained together, you could argue it's on-topic, but asking for help with something like `=A1-TODAY()` is just a [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) question.

Comment: I think that questions about things that are obviously already explained in the official documentation, i.e. [Add formulas & functions (in Google Sheets)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?hl=en), should not be allowed on SO and Web Apps... once having said that, there are several things that might be asked about `=A1-TODAY()` that might be on-topic here but those questions should be clear, include enough details a "mcve", etc. The same for asking those questions on Web Apps.

Answer (score 0):

As an [SME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert) on the topic, questions about Google Sheets are on-topic provided they are asking about:

- Google Apps Script (that provides the [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) service to programmatically control Google Sheets spreadsheets);
- creating and managing [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) (this basically belongs to the above as they are written in Apps Script);
- using the Google [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) and client libraries for it in various programming languages.

Questions that *just* ask how to do something with an in-built Google Sheets formula or a combination thereof are not trying to solve a programming problem, or ask about a tool *primarily* used by programmers. Nor do they establish any programming context.

Questions about the general usage of the Google Sheets platform as a service (as well as working with formulas) are best-suited for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) network site. The [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) tag has an extensive guide for how to ask about the platform.

Feel free to close them as "[Not about programming or software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/420218#420218)" that replaced the retired Super User and Server Fault close reasons.

Comment: Google Spreadsheets is a part of the Google Docs web app suite. Questions about Google Spreadsheets are off topic on [su] and should be asked on webapps.stackexchange.com, unless they specifically involve your computer or browser.

Comment: Weren't formulas on-topic as general computing, though, @DavidPostill? I remember the discussion about general questions of using Google Sheets as an app we had in our community, and that it belongs on Webapps indeed (I'll include that in the answer for sure, completely spaced out on that).

Comment: Google Spreadsheets have been off topic since 2011 on [su]

Comment: Granted, I am not particularly active on Super User, SO is my home, but I am not sure that restriction is applied to [formulas](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-spreadsheets%5D+closed%3Ano+score%3A1), @DavidPostill. Can you point me to a community consensus about what you are claiming? I'd love to be up to date with the topicality issues on the wider network so as not to misadvise.

Comment: My first quote is from ['google-spreadsheets' tag wiki - Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/google-spreadsheets/info) which was changed in 2011 to be off topic. It make no distinction that formulae are on topic.

Comment: [Super User website applications policy - Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/821/super-user-website-applications-policy) is a relevant meta discussion.

Comment: [Superuser off-topic restrictions](https://meta.superuser.com/a/1133/337631) by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: I can't find any more that - this was decided way before I joined [su] and later becoming a mod in 2017

Comment: thanks, @DavidPostill! I'll review the links as soon as I can, maybe even ask on SU meta regarding whether the distinction is made (I don't want to invoke the existing questions argument as I know full well that they often slip through the cracks due to the sheer size of the Trinity sites, but their presence bothers me, especially in light of the discussion above).

Comment: `Questions that just ask how to do something with an in-built Google Sheets formula... are not trying to solve a programming problem, or... any programming context` Disagree very much. What is a programming problem? Would you consider the Euclid's algorithm a programming problem? If a answer written in formula solved such a problem, would that be on-topic? This question deals with date differences. If the tag was javascript, would it automatically become a programming problem? I disagree that only tools with white on black text can be considered programming tools.

Comment: @TheMaster since we last had this discussion, I refined my stance on what constitutes programming in terms of using formulas, and what is just general computing. Specifically, I still have no gripe with questions on the behavior or syntax of formulas (as, indeed, a combination of those constitutes a program) - however, requests such as "give me a formula that does X" where the only known thing is the output I do not consider constituting programming context but rather them being questions on the usage of the application.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I don't think that's a right divider.  We see "gimme teh codez" questions all the time on other tags. If you use that as a divider, are these questions about usage of application: [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698556/), or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73699208/) and not a programming problem? We regularly get "gimme code that does X". Why should only code written in formulas be considered app usage? Last I checked, the consensus on "gimme teh codez" questions are not even considered "off-topic", unless they're too broad as well.